# connection link is not a resource?why?

Tags: php

I am using a class to create mysql connection and store the link in a private variable,

but when I am using that link variable in mysql_real_escape_string() or try to use

is_resource() it says the link is not a resource.... here is my class code from library.php...

```
class db_system
{
    private $link;
    private $result;

    /*
        Constructor connects to database and store in link
    */
public function __construct()
{
    $lines = file('../../secret/topsecret');
    $this->link = mysqli_connect(trim($lines[0]), trim($lines[1]), trim($lines[2]), trim($lines[3])) or die("Could not connect to " . mysqli_error($this->link));
    if(is_resource($this->link))
        echo "true";
    else
        echo "false";  // it always prints false;
}

/*
    this method process the query and returns the result od the query
*/
public function sqlquery($query)
{
    $this->result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query) or die('query failed ' . mysqli_error($this->link));
}

/*
    this method returns the rows in an array form
*/
public function get_data()
{
    return mysqli_fetch_array($this->result);
}

/*
    destructor closes sql connection if link is active
*/
public function __destruct()
{
    if($this->link)
    {
        mysqli_close($this->link);
    }
}

public function getlink()
{
    return $this->link;
}
}
```

Here is the code from view.php

```
include 'library.php';

    $view = new db_system();  // connection object made

$per = "%";

$qry = sprintf('SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE description LIKE     "%s%s%s"',$per,mysql_real_escape_string($find,$view->getlink()),$per);
```

// $find is a value to be searched which comes from $_GET['find'] and is stored in $find and is not null

After this it says 2 parameter is not a resource in mysql_real_escape_string().....

So how do I make the $link as resource variable so that i can use mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: Because of this probably `mysql_real_escape_string` you're mixing APIs, **don't**.

Comment: so what else should I use to prevent sql injection

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` with the `i` ;-)

Comment: If you want to know why you are getting this error, is simply because you are passing an `mysqli_` link to a `mysql_` function. So don't mix apis.

Comment: Did you try omitting `is_resource()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because mysqli doesn't use resources, it uses objects:

```
mysqli mysqli_connect ([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") [, string $passwd = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") [, string $dbname = "" [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") [, string $socket = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )
```

This says the function returns an object of type `mysqli` (first word on that line).

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php. Also see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php for how to properly escape/parameterize queries instead of using the unrelated `mysql_real_escape_string`.